# "Show Custom Logo in Meeting Requests" option missing?

Tags: email, metadata-api, metadata, event, activity

For some reason, the option to set custom logos in meeting requests is missing from my Activity Settings.

I can't find any reference to this setting being removed, in fact, I can find at [least](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000iULAQA2) these [two](http://www.simplysfdc.com/2016/05/salesforce-new-event-versus-new-meeting.html) articles which reference this setting from last year. However, I can't find anything newer which references this setting.

I've checked my developer org, my production org, multiple sandboxes, and a scratch org, and I still can't find this setting.

Is there some condition that I haven't met that isn't documented? Did this setting get removed in a past update? How can I set this or an equivalent setting?

[image]

Comment: While I may have written an answer about how I was able to overcome this bug (I think?), I would be interested in why I'm still unable to access this setting, or any other approaches to modifying the setting.

Comment: Found another setting missing - "Show Calendar Link in Sidebar" - had to perform the same actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution to this is probably overkill, but without a way to edit the setting through the UI, I needed a way to access it.

Using the Metadata API through the workbench, I was able to obtain the `Activities.settings` file for my org. Using the following `package.xml` file, uploaded through [Workbench's Metadata retrieve](https://workbench.developerforce.com/metadataRetrieve.php).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Settings</name>
    </types>
    <version>41.0</version>
</Package>
```

Once I had the file, all I needed to do was set `showCustomLogoMeetingRequests` from `false` to `true`. The resulting data looked like this:

```
<showCustomLogoMeetingRequests>true</showCustomLogoMeetingRequests>
<meetingRequestsLogo>SharedDocuments/SomeLogo.jpg</meetingRequestsLogo>
```

I then compressed these files into a `.zip` file, using this command (as I'm on a mac, and needed to remove the `.DS_Store` files from the package):

```
zip -r src.zip src -x "*.DS_Store"
```

The resulting structure of the files looked like this:

```
-src    
    -package.xml 
    -settings
        -Activities.settings
```

I uploaded the `zip` file into the [Metadata Deploy Page of Workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/metadataDeploy.php), and set the required options to deploy to production (Rollback On Error, Test Level - Run Local Tests). Once the deploy was finished, the setting was enabled for the org, and set to my option.

However, the setting for `showCustomLogoMeetingRequests` still isn't visible, but the lookup field for `meetingRequestsLogo` is displayed. Despite the setting not being available in the UI, at least I can change the logo if needed, and all emails for meetings are going out with the company logo.

[image]